# Userform input only works once

Tags: excel, vba

I have this userform and VBA code to input data on different sheets within the workbook depending on one combobox value.

Everything works for one entry. If I try to add another payment it gives me

> "Run-time error '1004"

It gets stuck at

```
oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_ReceiptNo.Value
```

```
Private Sub ComboBox_PaymentDay_Change()
Sheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value).Activate
paymenttable = "payment" & Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value
Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_AddPayment_Click()
    'Check for empty or False value for all checkbox and exit before submitting the form
Dim paymenttable As Variant
paymenttable = "payment" & Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value
Dim currentsheet As Worksheet
Sheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value).Activate
With Payment_Form
    If TextBox_ReceiptNo.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Receipt Number is required"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf TextBox_Name.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Name is required"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf OptionButton_Cheque.Value = True Then
        If TextBox_ChequeNo.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Cheque Number is Required"
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf ComboBox_Bank.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please Select a Bank"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ElseIf ComboBox_Currency.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Currency"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf TextBox_Amount.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Amount is required"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf OptionButton_Other.Value = True Then
        If TextBox_Code.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Account Code is Required"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End With

    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Dim oNewRow As ListRow

    Dim rng As Range
    Sheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value).Activate
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value).Range(paymenttable)
    rng.Select
    Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    Sheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value).Unprotect Password:="0000"

    With Sheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value)
        Debug.Print Payment_Form.TextBox_ReceiptNo.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_ReceiptNo.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_Name.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox_ChequeNo.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 4).Value = Me.DTPicker_ChequeDate.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 5).Value = Me.ComboBox_Bank.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 6).Value = Me.ComboBox_Currency.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).Value = Me.TextBox_Amount.Value
        If OptionButton_Cheque.Value = True Then
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Cheque"
        Else
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Cash"
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 4).Value = "N/A"
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 3).Value = "N/A"
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 5).Value = "N/A"
        End If
        If OptionButton_Receivables.Value = True Then
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Receivables"
        Else
            oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Other"
        End If
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 14).Value = Me.TextBox_Code.Value
        Me.TextBox_ReceiptNo.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox_Name.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox_ChequeNo.Value = ""
        'Me.DTPicker_ChequeDate.Value = ""
        Me.ComboBox_Bank.Value = ""
        Me.ComboBox_Currency.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox_Amount.Value = ""
        Set oNewRow = Nothing
    End With

    'Load Payment_Form
    Unload Me
    Sheets(Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value).Protect Password:="0000"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_CloseForm_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton_Cash_Click()
If OptionButton_Cash.Value = True Then
    Frame_ChequeData.Enabled = False
    Frame_ChequeData.Visible = False
    Else
    Frame_ChequeData.Enabled = True
    Frame_ChequeData.Visible = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton_Cheque_Click()
If OptionButton_Cheque.Value = True Then
    Frame_ChequeData.Enabled = True
    Frame_ChequeData.Visible = True
    Else
    Frame_ChequeData.Enabled = False
    Frame_ChequeData.Visible = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton_Receivables_Click()
If OptionButton_Receivables.Value = True Then
    Frame_Other.Enabled = False
    Frame_Other.Visible = False
Else
    Frame_Other.Enabled = True
    Frame_Other.Visible = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton_Other_Click()
If OptionButton_Other.Value = True Then
    Frame_Other.Enabled = True
    Frame_Other.Visible = True
    Else
    Frame_Other.Enabled = False
    Frame_Other.Visible = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.Value = Day(Date)
Dim BanksArray As Variant
Dim CurrencyArray As Variant

CurrencyArray = Array("EGP E£", "USD $", "EURO €")
BanksArray = Array("Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank (ADIB)", "Agricultural Bank of Egypt", "Ahli United Bank", "Al Ahli Bank of Kuwait - Egypt (ABK-Egypt)", "Al Baraka Bank of Egypt", "Arab African International Bank", "Arab Bank Plc.", "Arab Banking Corporation (Bank ABC)", "Arab International Bank", "Arab Investment Bank (AIBK)", "Attijariwafa Bank Egypt", "Bank Audi", "Bank of Alexandria", "Banque du Caire", "Banque Misr", "Blom Bank", "Citibank", "Commercial International Bank (CIB)", "Credit Agricole Egypt", "Egyptian Arab Land Bank", "Egyptian Gulf Bank (EG BANK)", "Emirates NBD", "Export Development Bank of Egypt", "Faisal Islamic Bank of Egypt", "First Abu Dhabi Bank (FAB)", "Housing and Development Bank", "HSBC Bank Egypt", "Industrial Development & Workers Bank of Egypt", "Misr Iran Development Bank", "National Bank of Egypt", "National Bank of Greece", _
"National Bank of Kuwait - Egypt (NBK-Egypt)", "Qatar National Bank Al Ahli (QNB Alahli)", "Société Arabe Internationale de Banque (SAIB)", "Suez Canal Bank", "The United Bank of Egypt", "Union National Bank Egypt (UNB-E)")
    Me.ComboBox_Bank.List = BanksArray
    Me.ComboBox_Currency.List = CurrencyArray
    Me.ComboBox_PaymentDay.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_ReceiptNo_Change()
    OnlyNumbers
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_Amount_Change()
    OnlyNumbers
End Sub

Private Sub OnlyNumbers()
    If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "TextBox" Then
        With Me.ActiveControl
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
                .Value = vbNullString
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I have to clean up my code and add more functionality, however I can't get myself to do more as I can't figure this out.

Comment: Debug through your code, and find out which exact line generates an exception.

Comment: Agree with what Vitaliy says, the best way to achieve this is to go into the design view and use Shift+F8 to step through the code until the error occurs.  Can you show us what the data looks like?

Comment: I already looked at the debugger... It gets stuck at.. '''oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_ReceiptNo.Value'''

Comment: You've got alot of things inside a with statement that probably shouldn't be there. I'm also not seeing anywhere that you're using the functionality of the With Statement.

Comment: I have tried it without with statement and still gets stuck after one posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the my issue by replacing

```
Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
```

with

```
Set tbl = Range(paymenttable).ListObject

Set oNewRow = tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
```